# BootStrap 3 Two Nav headers on the same row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a basic BootStrap 3 nav header. I would like to separate the existing header so that I have the single dropdown item on the far right, and the rest of the other main menu items to be on the far left. Not sure how to do this?

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Cost Tracking</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-header -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-left" style="margin-left:96px">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Project Details</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Cost Centre</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Address Book</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Time Tracking</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Reports</button>               
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>                    
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">                      
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
        </ul>
        <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

        <div class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">                     
                    <li class="sidebar-search">
                        <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                    </li>
                    <li class="background-color:#333">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Project Info</a>                            
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Project Roles</a>                            
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Rate Schedule Review</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Surcharges</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-group fa-fw"></i> Project Crews</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Project Employees</a>
                    </li>                        
                </ul>
                <!-- /#side-menu -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
    </nav>
```

Comment: Can you post your full HTML.  I don't see your `.navbar` anywhere.  Also, maybe a screenshot of what it looks like and what you'd like it to look like.

Comment: You could use [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or [bootply](http://www.bootply.com) to show us what's going on.

Comment: sorry, re-posted with the full HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs to have a navigation over to the right hand side of the navbar you need to place it in it's own `<ul>`:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </a>                    
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">                      
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
    </li>
    <!-- /.dropdown -->
</ul>
```

As a side note, the only direct child of a `<ul>` can be a `<li>`, so your `<button>`s need to be wrapped in list elements:

```
<li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Project Details</button></li>
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/cadac/1/edit)**

---

If you don't want it in a separate list, then you'll have to override the float on the `<ul>` and then float the final `<li>` right.  You'll also need the `.dropdown-menu-right` class on the dropdown `<ul>`.

```
...
<li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Reports</button></li>
<li class="dropdown pull-right">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-user">                      
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-nav {
  float: none;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/cadac/2/edit)**

Comment: Thanks David. I was wondering though, if I wanted my left top menu to have a margin of say 280px from the left, but to not have that margin when I shrink the screen, how would I best achieve that?

Comment: Thanks Dave. I marked your answer as correct. Any advice on how to bring back the spacing that I previously had between the buttons (top and in between)? I think the they got messed up with the float:none

Comment: No problem.  Why not just add a margin to line the items up? http://jsbin.com/cadac/4/edit

Comment: Thanks mate (just realised you're an Aussie). G'day from Canada! (fellow Aussie).

Comment: Haha I'm not actually an Aussie, I'm from the UK working in Sydney.  G'day nonetheless!